# When I try to concatenate word with equation related to date sql plus

Tags: sql

When I trying to have cell like 
Words then calculated period sysdate - hire date from table

```
Select 'and his experience about' ||' '|| sysdate - hire_date 
from employees
```

I didn't get result -error
Need help plz

Comment: `||` wants character data, not date/time. cast sysdate - hire_date as varchar.

Comment: String manipulation tends to be very product specific. Please tag your question with the specific database that you're using. [Why should I “tag my RDBMS”?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms)

Answer (score 0):

Try :

Select 'and his experience about' + ' ' + CONVERT(varchar, getdate() - hire_date, 23) 
from employees

23 is for yyyy-mm-dd format. For all others format see at :
https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1145/date-and-time-conversions-using-sql-server/

Comment: This assumes SQL Server (`CONVERT` function), but the pipe concatenation suggests otherwise.

Comment: ok maybe a MySql DB, use : date_format(sysdate() - hire_date ,'%Y-%m-%d') 
instead of convert function